# Unit testing file upload in a controller with Java Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: java, scala, junit, playframework, playframework-2.3

After working most of the day I feel like I am fairly close to a solution on how to test a controller method which accepts file uploads from JUnit.  My juint test code is as follows:

```
Map<String, String> postData = makePostMap(uploadForm);
File file = new File("test/resources/shared/uploads/blank.csv");
TemporaryFile temporaryFile = new TemporaryFile(file);

MultipartFormData.FilePart filePath = new MultipartFormData.FilePart(
        "file",
        "file.csv",
        new scala.Some<>("text/csv"),
        temporaryFile);

List<MultipartFormData.FilePart> fileParts = Lists.newArrayList(filePath);
scala.collection.immutable.Seq files = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(fileParts).toList();

Map<String, scala.collection.immutable.Seq<String>> postData2 = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : postData.keySet()) {
    postData2.put(s, JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Lists.newArrayList(postData.get(s))).toList());
}
scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, scala.collection.immutable.Seq<String>> scalaMap =
        JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(postData2).toMap(Predef.<Tuple2<String, scala.collection.immutable.Seq<String>>>conforms());

MultipartFormData formData = new MultipartFormData(scalaMap, files, null, null);
AnyContentAsMultipartFormData body = new AnyContentAsMultipartFormData(formData);

// run
login(employee);
String url = routes.ManageContacts.uploadCsv().url();
FakeRequest fakeRequest = new FakeRequest(POST, url).withBody(body);
fakeRequest = getAuthenticatedRequest(fakeRequest, employee);

result = route(fakeRequest);

assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK)
```

However, I get an exception (below) when the FakeRequest is routed to.

```
[error] Test controllers.ManageContactsTest.testUploadCsv failed: scala.MatchError: AnyContentAsMultipartFormData(MultipartFormData(Map(clearExisting -> List(false), survey -> List(11), bosMode -> List(false)),List(FilePart(file,file.csv,Some(text/csv),TemporaryFile(test/resources/shared/uploads/blank.csv))),null,null)) (of class play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsMultipartFormData), took 0.255 sec
[error]     at play.api.test.RouteInvokers$class.jRoute(Helpers.scala:255)
[error]     at play.api.test.Helpers$.jRoute(Helpers.scala:403)
[error]     at play.api.test.Helpers.jRoute(Helpers.scala)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.route(Helpers.java:445)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.route(Helpers.java:437)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.route(Helpers.java:433)
[error]     at controllers.ManageContactsTest.testUploadCsv(ManageContactsTest.java:121)
[error]     ...
```

Diving down into the stack trace, I find the following scala match statement in the file: 
`/Users/jcreason/bin/playframework-2.3.8/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala:253`

```
  def jRoute[T](app: Application, r: FakeRequest[T]): Option[Future[Result]] = {
    (r.body: @unchecked) match {
      case body: AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded => route(app, r, body)
      case body: AnyContentAsJson => route(app, r, body)
      case body: AnyContentAsXml => route(app, r, body)
      case body: AnyContentAsText => route(app, r, body)
      case body: AnyContentAsRaw => route(app, r, body)
      case body: AnyContentAsEmpty.type => route(app, r, body)
      //case _ => MatchError is thrown
    }
  }
```

Since I'm passing through `AnyContentAsMultipartFormData`, it throws this exception as it's not handled by the match.  Does anyone know how to get around this?  Or could point me in the direction of a different solution to this (aside from obvious answers just as selenium)?

For reference, I pulled some of this code from:

http://www.erol.si/2014/02/how-to-test-file-uploads-in-play-framework-java/

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the article. I tested this with Play 2.2 but it seems that few things changed. 

I will test it with newer version, but meanwhile you can check example in scala https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9f258fcd248ea79ad38f0fddfe4192a2ccf4afb0/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/upload/code/ScalaFileUpload.scala

Comment: As you are using Java maybe it will help to look at this: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9f258fcd248ea79ad38f0fddfe4192a2ccf4afb0/documentation/manual/working/javaGuide/main/upload/code/JavaFileUpload.java

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FrEaKmAn, I'll try to checkout that Scala version when I get a free moment, thanks.

Comment: @Anton, unfortunately that example is from the perspective of the receiver (Controller), and I was trying to automate from the client's perspective, or the user of the file upload.

Comment: @jcreason Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I haven't @Kris, I meant to play with it more, but haven't been able to find the time.

Answer (score 1):

This code may be useful:

```
import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import akka.util.ByteString;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.*;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestBuilder;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.test.*;

class UploadFileTest extends WithApplication {
    @Test
    public void uploadTest() {
        Part<Source<ByteString, ?>> part = new FilePart<>("key", "fileName", "application/octet-stream",
                Source.empty());
        List<Part<Source<ByteString, ?>>> data = Arrays.asList(part);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = fakeRequest(controllers.routes.UploadController.upload()).method(POST)
                .bodyMultipart(data, mat);

        Result result = route(app, requestBuilder);

        assertEquals(Helpers.OK, result.status());
    }
}
```

If you want to send not empty file,
 instead of `Source.empty()` use `FileIO.fromFile(new File("path/to/file"))`;