# Play 2.4: How to write a test case for file upload with MultipartFormData

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

So far (up to Play 2.3) to create a mock request I used `Helpers.fakeRequest().withAnyContent()`. E.g.

```
private Request getMultiPartFormDataRequestForFileUpload(File file,
        String filePartKey, String contentType) {
    FilePart<TemporaryFile> part = new MultipartFormData.FilePart<>(
            filePartKey, file.getName(), Scala.Option(contentType),
            new TemporaryFile(file));
    List<FilePart<TemporaryFile>> fileParts = new ArrayList<>();
    fileParts.add(part);
    scala.collection.immutable.List<FilePart<TemporaryFile>> files = scala.collection.JavaConversions
            .asScalaBuffer(fileParts).toList();
    MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile> formData = new MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile>(
            null, files, null, null);
    return Helpers.fakeRequest().withAnyContent(formData);
}
```

In Play 2.4 this isn't possible any more. If I look at the source of [RequestBuilder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.3/api/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestBuilder.html) (which is implemented by FakeRequest) a similar function exist, but it's protected and I can't use it.

```
protected Http.RequestBuilder   body(play.api.mvc.AnyContent anyContent)
Set a AnyContent to this request.
```

Does anyone know how I can write a test case to check a file upload with MultipartFormData in 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

As Helpers.fakeRequest is a very, very simple method (taken from github)

```
/**
 * Build a new GET / fake request.
 */
public static RequestBuilder fakeRequest() {
    return fakeRequest("GET", "/");
}

/**
 * Build a new fake request.
 */
public static RequestBuilder fakeRequest(String method, String uri) {
    return new RequestBuilder().method(method).uri(uri);
}
```

you can extend Http.RequestBuilder thus getting access to protected method:

```
public class FakeRequestBuilder extends HttpRequestBuilder() {
   public RequestBuilder setAnyBody(RequestBody body, String contentType) {
     header("Content-Type", contentType);
     body(body);
   }
}
```

And use that in your test:

```
 //OLD return Helpers.fakeRequest().withAnyContent(formData);
 //NEW
 return new FakeRequestBuilder().setAnyBody(formData, "multipart/form-data").build(); 
 //or is it application/x-www-form-urlencoded for you?
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later.

Comment: Thank you Jan, but it didn't work. Sorry for the late reply (better late than never). With your FakeRequestBuilder I get an `scala.MatchError: AnyContentAsMultipartFormData`. But my content type is "application/zip". I guess it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791562/unit-testing-file-upload-in-a-controller-with-java-play-framework-2-3-x.

Answer (score 0):

In Play2.4, body() does not accept a RequestBody, and you have to create an AnyContent from multipart first. Example:

```
private class FakeRequestBuilder extends Http.RequestBuilder {
    public FakeRequestBuilder(String method, String uri) {
        method(method).uri(uri);
    }

    protected RequestBuilder setAnyBody(MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile> formData, String contentType) {
        header("Content-Type", contentType);
        AnyContent anyContent = new AnyContentAsMultipartFormData(formData);
        body(anyContent);
        return this;
    }
}
```

A MultiPartFormData thingie can be created by this for example:

```
private MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile> createFormData(String contentType, String filePartKey, File file) {
    FilePart<TemporaryFile> part = new MultipartFormData.FilePart<>(filePartKey, file.getName(), Scala.Option(contentType), new TemporaryFile(file));
    List<FilePart<TemporaryFile>> fileParts = new ArrayList<>();
    fileParts.add(part);
    scala.collection.immutable.List<FilePart<TemporaryFile>> files = scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(fileParts).toList();
    MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile> formData = new MultipartFormData<TemporaryFile>(null, files, null, null);
    return formData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution. And I also tried using a mock with Mockito. With both I end up with an `scala.MatchError: AnyContentAsMultipartFormData` which seems to be the one from this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791562/unit-testing-file-upload-in-a-controller-with-java-play-framework-2-3-x.